# Laravel. Получение данных из таблицы БД

Tags: база-данных, laravel, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть таблица виз **Visas** со следующей структурой:
**'id'|'client_id'|'place_get_visa'**

В 'place_get_visa' во view записываются цифры от 1 до 3. Каждая характеризует определённый город.
Есть вторая таблица **Visa_receipt_place**, где записаны города в которых получена виза:
**'id', 'place_get'** 

В place_get заданы названия городов.
Между ними есть связь один ко одному. В модели **Visas**:

```
public function getPlace(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Visa_receipt_place', 'id', 'place_get_visa');
}
```

В модели **Visa_receipt_place**:

```
 public function getVisa(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Visas', 'place_get_visa', 'id')->get(); 
 }
```

Вопрос: как правильно сделать вывод во view данных из таблицы  **Visas**, но при этом, чтобы вместо цифр в **'place_get_visa'** было название выбранных городов из таблицы **Visa_receipt_place** которое там записано в столбце **'place_get'**?

Answer (score 0):

Можно обратиться через название вашего метода в классе Visas.

```
$visas = Visas::with("getPlace")->find(1);
$visas->getPlace->поле_из_таблицы_Place;
```

Но стоит изучить лучше [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) и посмотрите в сторону [жадной загрузки](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).